# Why is python improperly converting these datetime strings?

Tags: python, datetime

Take alook at the following idle session:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> timeFmtPy = '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S %p'
>>> d = lambda y:datetime.strptime(y, timeFmtPy)
>>> t1 = d('6/2/2019 12:48:10 AM')
>>> t2 = d('6/2/2019 1:05:17 AM')
>>>
>>> (t2-t1)
datetime.timedelta(days=-1, seconds=44227)
>>> 44227/3600
12.285277777777777
>>> (t2-t1).total_seconds()
-42173.0
```

Clearly, `t2` is later than `t1`. Does anyone know why the difference is negative when it should be positive?

Comment: "I would have looked into this more if I had some time." - then, take the time and don't let others do it. Oh, and BTW, 12 AM is midnight.

Comment: wow, am i missing something obvious??

Comment: @ThomasWeller and 1 a.m is not?

Comment: @frederick99 12:48:10 ? You cannot have that time in a 12 hour clock

Comment: @Rahul yes you can. the problem was i had to use `%I` for 12-hour... hours.. and not `%H`.

Comment: @frederick99 I meant in AM not PM as you have written in the question, it would be 00:48:10 AM

Comment: Folks, if you can ignore the footnote (that I removed), this is actually a pretty OK question that I'm sure a lot of people have issues with.

Comment: @cs95 i guess it was the footnote especially that attracted all the downvotes and i can toatlly understand that. oh well :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're specifying time in 12-hr format, so `%H` should've been `%I`.

```
f = lambda y: datetime.strptime(y, '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')
t1 = f('6/2/2019 12:48:10 AM')
t2 = f('6/2/2019 1:05:17 AM')

t2 > t1
# True
```

See http://strftime.org for a convenient listing of time format specifiers.

Comment: @frederick99 Just FYI I didn't answer your question because it was urgent, I did so because it seemed like an honest enough mistake that enough people trip up on, so it was worth writing an answer for. Please do your due diligence in research before asking a question, for future reference.

Comment: yes, i agree. i know it was my bad. i usually look really hard before asking a question on here but i was running really late. i know it sounds like an excuse please forgive me. :l